# Adjusting the whole width of the website, how do I do this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's basically what I'm trying to do: http://prntscr.com/nq83xo

I'm trying to make the whole website width limited to a part of the screen but I can't find how to do so. I've tried flexbox and adjusting the body width but none seem to work.

Note that I'm a beginner.

Comment: Please add all information to the question. Don't link to other sources to explain the basich problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `html width`. If you want the site centered on the screen, use `margin:0px auto` on the div that should be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to help without code. Can try though. What is the next child after the `<body>` tag? What you're going to want to do is declare a `max-width` as well as something like `width: 100%` on all tags that are direct descendents of the `<body>` tag.

When you do that all of your content should be on the left side of the screen. To center you should do `margin: 0 auto`

here's a codepen of what I am thinking.
https://codepen.io/axecopfire/pen/zQzebO

Answer (score 0):

Create an `<iframe>` and update your webpage inside the frame, then apply desired width to the frame :

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#holder {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: flex;
 position: relative;
}

#newContent {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="holder">
  <iframe id="newContent" src="http://YourURLGoesHere/">
  </iframe>
 </div>
</body>
```